# AWS hosted website not working, what would be the problem?

Tags: amazon-web-services

please advise me.

I am no developer and very new to this. Our website is down and it keeps showing the following error:

This site can’t be reached
The connection was reset.

We are using AWS. 
It keeps happening every few weeks. I tried redirecting it on AWS to a different website, for the time being, that didn't work either. 
Any help is appreciated

Comment: Can you add more details to the configuration you're using? (S3, EC2, ..., ) The more details, the better.

Comment: Hi Mathieu, Thank you for replying. I'm not very familiar with this, from research it seems like the configuration was done wrong. The folders for a static website is on S3 and it seems like and there is an instant running in EC2. I don't have much knwoledge on the AWS ask me for any more information if needed.

Answer (score 0):

If the website is hosted in EC2 instance

- Check if your EC2 instance is having the same ip as earlier if it doesn't have a elastic ip associated with it chances are any restart of that ec2 instance might have changed the public ip address.
- If above is same as earlier check the security group if it allows traffic on port 80 and 443 ( if using ssl )
- And most importantly check if your website is indeed running i.e check with IP address in web browser i.e `http://<ip_address>:<port>/` or `https://<ip_address>:<port>/`

Comment: Hi Jeet, Thank you for your reply.

Comment: 1. I checked the EC2 instances it has an elastic IP address. 2. I checked the security groups, HTTP TCP port range is 80 and SSH TCP is 22.    3. it is running, just shows 'this site cant be reached'

Comment: How do you confirm that the site is running?

Comment: Its very kind of you to follow up on this. I checked it on a website that tells you whether a website is up or down. I copy and paste the IP address and tried running it that way. same problem

Comment: I don't think the website will be helpful in verification, because they just try to access the index page, and if thats there they confirm the working of it. That doesn't mean website is working, i.e index page could be error also. So please check the website in reliable ways to confirm its working.

Comment: I hired someone to fix it, it's working now.  They created a snapshot,

Comment: They created a snapshot, the website didn't have any SSH. Then created a new server and moved the snapshot to a new server. (i can't make sense of it, but it's working now)